# kogito return process instance not found after restart the service

Tags: quarkus, kogito

I need some advice and explanation, according to my case. here is my kogito setup:

kogito service --> dataIndex-postgresql-->Kogito Management Console --> Kogito Task Console.

I create simple BPMN, it is just Task User.

Test scenario:

1. Service kogito, Console Management and task console Run,Then I submit the workflow until the phases complete in Task Console management.
2. Service kogito, Console Management and task console Run. Submit the wofkflow then the task success waiting in task console, then i **stop** the kogito service then run it again the kogito service. the task console will returned error "process instance with id 2493dndnxxx not found. when i try to post the task console.

I don't understand why. I really appreciate if some one can explain for this case, it is normal or not ?.

Thank you

i expect some one can explain this is normal situation or not ?.

in my understanding the process instance Id can submited the task even i stop the kogito service because we have dataIndex with postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Kogito service is ephemeral by default, which means any process started will be lost if you restart the service. To maintain the state, you must add one of the persistence add-ons to your Kogito runtime project. See the docs here for more information about the supported persistence types https://docs.kogito.kie.org/latest/html_single/#con-persistence_kogito-developing-process-services.

In this other section,there are also some more details about how that can be combined when using other services like Data Index, which also supports different persistency types: https://docs.kogito.kie.org/latest/html_single/#con-data-index-service_kogito-configuring